# Stored Procedure within a Stored Procedure NVARCHAR output value

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one stored procedure which return a nvarchar value written like that:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLastVouchNumber]
  @returnVal nvarchar(255) output

AS
BEGIN

SET @returnVal = ( SELECT CONCAT('I',VOUCHNO+1)
FROM TABVOU
WHERE VOUCHER = 'VOUCHER#')


END
```

I am trying to use the output value from this procedure in another procedure. And this was how I try to write this new procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MassAdjInsertIntoYTDTRNI]
 @inputPeriod nvarchar(255),
 @inputUserId nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @resultOrdNo nvarchar (255)
 DECLARE @newOrdNo nvarchar(255)

 EXEC @newOrdNo = GetLastVouchNumber @resultOrdNo

 INSERT INTO  YTDTRNI(TRCDE,PROD,WH,DESCR,UCOST,TCOST,DRAC,CRAC,REM,QTY,UM,ORDNO,TRDATE,SYSDATE,PERIOD,USERID)
 SELECT 'AJ',PROD,WH,DESCR,0,-TCOST,STKGL,COSGL,'MASS ADJUSTMENT',0,UM,@newOrdNo, GETDATE(),GETDATE(),@inputPeriod,@inputUserId
```

FROM INV

I was assuming that this line:

```
EXEC @newOrdNo = GetLastVouchNumber @resultOrdNo
```

will store the result of the first procedure into @newOrdNo then after that I can use this @newOrdNo to insert it into another table. But after I execute this second stored procedure, the ORDNO column does not contain any values...

Need advice.

Comment: Why did you need to use `SP` call `SP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OUTPUT` keyword when you call `GetLastVouchNumber` and pass `@newOrdNo` as an output parameter. Your `GetLastVouchNumber` procedure returns information with output parameter.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MassAdjInsertIntoYTDTRNI]
    @inputPeriod nvarchar(255),
    @inputUserId nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @resultOrdNo nvarchar (255)
    DECLARE @newOrdNo nvarchar(255)

    -- Call your stored procedure
    EXEC GetLastVouchNumber @newOrdNo OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO YTDTRNI(TRCDE,PROD,WH,DESCR,UCOST,TCOST,DRAC,CRAC,REM,QTY,UM,ORDNO,TRDATE,SYSDATE,PERIOD,USERID)
    SELECT 'AJ',PROD,WH,DESCR,0,-TCOST,STKGL,COSGL,'MASS ADJUSTMENT',0,UM,@newOrdNo, GETDATE(),GETDATE(),@inputPeriod,@inputUserId

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You seemed to have confused a *return value* and an *output variable*. Your stored proc uses the latter for returning your value, and does not explicitly return anything (Albeit confusing, as you have named your output variable `returnVal`).

When you call it, you must specify the `OUTPUT`

```
 EXEC GetLastVouchNumber @resultOrdNo OUTPUT
```